# How can I get rid of the click off event on an autopicker with tags in a moodle form?

Tags: php, autocomplete, moodle, moodle-api

I am using the autocomplete element from the Moodle Form API on a Moodle form. I preload the autocomplete element with a list, set multiple to true, and tags to true. This allows the user to add elements to the list if they don't already exist. A user can add an element by typing in the text and either clicking enter or clicking off of the autocomplete element. This event will take whatever the text is in the autocomplete and add it to the list. I don't want an element to be made every time the user has entered text and clicks off of the autocomplete, rather just when the user has entered text and clicks enter. Is there a way to do this using Moodle's Form API autocomplete or should I go about this a different way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy solution to this issue.  However I believe I have started to find a way to do what you would like.  If you go into `lib\amd\src\form-autocomplete.js` and head down to about line 728 (using Moodle version 3.7) you will see this line:

```
return createItem(options, state, originalSelect);
```

This is the line that triggers the creation of a new tag whenever the auto-picker gets its focus lost (click off).  If you comment out this line, that click off event will no longer trigger that creation.  However it must be noted that this will cause it to be disabled across your whole site, for all auto-pickers.

Obviously I do NOT recommend doing this, as with it being a core Moodle function it will most likely revert as soon as you update Moodle, causing many potential issues down the road.  However, as this question has not seemed to get much attention, I wanted to add this just to give you and/or other people viewing this somewhere to start.

I am currently looking into creating a copy of `autocomplete.php` (the php element that mform uses for auto-pickers) and adjusting its calls to use a separate, slightly adjusted version of `lib\amd\src\form-autocomplete.js`.  I will update you with any progress I personally make, but hopefully this information can get the ball rolling for you or other developers on this site.